# Exception upon creating a facebook app for windows 8.1 using C# & XAML

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm following http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/tutorial/ . When I reached "You should now be able to run the app and login to Facebook." in the above mentioned link I tried to run my app.

But it fails showing https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTT4K.png

How do I know that the error exists in the mentioned line because when I comment the line

```
//public static FacebookSessionClient facebookSessionClient = new FacebookSessionClient(Facebook_2.ViewModel.Constants.FacebookAppId);
```

Everything works fine.

This is not a duplicate post.

Comment: My Complete Code at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brh09szot8yd52x/Facebook_2.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting hours in this problem, I've found the solution.

Simply remove Facebook and Facebook.Client from Resources and add Facebook and Facebook.Client from the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5csbte4qb43imq5/AABuepVtxUcAzx8zD4aas1Qoa